# Can I display a Rotten Tomatoes/IMDB score on my movie website under fair use?

Tags: copyright, fair-use

I created a website which lists movies playing in cinemas in a geographical area.

For each movie, I would like to show the IMDB/Rotten Tomatoes scores.

I would not use their graphics, logos, labels (like "Rotten", "Fresh" etc). Just simply quoting the  (numeric) score published by IMDB/Rotten Tomatoes.

Any reason I would not be allowed to do that? Would that fall under fair use?

Comment: Read https://www.imdb.com/conditions